# Yii view not work, EColumnsDialog

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

picture shows what I have and what they want to have

[image]

```
'columns' => array(
            array(
                'header' => 'id',
                'name' => 'id',
                'value'=>'$data->id',
            ),
```

I have to do so that the "value => id" instead display an NO.ID Started to display an TXT_ ID NO.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using createCommand

```
 Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT CONCAT('TXT ',id),other_fields.. FROM table WHERE 1');
```

Comment: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.id

Comment: another and as for the help of $ this> render do the same?  

public function actionTest($type){
        $this->render('Item', array(
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'type' => $type,
        ));
    }  

and now instead of TXT display the $ type

Answer (score 1):

This will definitely help you

```
 'columns' => array(
             array(
                    'header' => 'id',
                    'name'   => 'id',
                    'value'  =>'$data->id',
                    'type'   =>'raw',
                    "value"  => function($data){
                        echo  "TXT ".$data->id;

                    },
              ),
```

Comment: how to get the same effect with Yii::app()->db->createCommand ?

Comment: Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1');